# Django urls py. Loading the index page instead of the image

Tags: python, django

I currently have two situations

A) http://127.0.0.1:8000/
B) http://127.0.0.1:8000/Images/SomeImages.png

This is what my urls.py looks like

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'',       include("webSite.urls")),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and then my webSite.urls looks like this

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r"", test , name="test"),
]
```

The problem with this is it works for condition A but for condition B it routes to the main page as well instead of the image. Can anyone tell me how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include the `^` and `$` anchors to mark the start and end of the string:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', test , name="test"),
]
```

or work with a `path(…)` which will compile a regex with these anchors:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', test , name="test"),
]
```